# Can a JSF 2.0 Composite Component emit a custom event?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, composite-component

I have a JSF 2.0 Composite Component which performs a database operation.

Can this Composite Component call a listener method as soon as this database operation has been performed? 
(This listener method will be in the backing bean of the page which uses the Composite Component)

Answer (score 1):

You could define a custom event and publish this event form your component. The event should subclass ComponentSystemEvent and needs to be published using UIComponent.publishEvent().

You could register custom event handlers, in this case an implementation of ComponentSystemEventListener, declaratively using f:Event or programmatically using Application.subscibeToEvent() or UIComponent.subscribeToEvent()

Comment: Are there any tutorials about this in the Web? (preferably with downloadable source code)

Comment: I am working on a tutorial for this, should be ready in the next few days. I'll let you know.